# Serial downvoting reversed - but the answers' score is still not up

Tags: support, down-votes

I had a few answers serially downvoted today before 3am UTC and then at 3am the reversal script restored my rep that I lost which is nice.

The affected answers still have lowered score though, at least on the mobile website.Is it a bug or is it going to sort itself out later? I would think that it should be all ok after the reversal script.

Comment: Did you get a chance to compare what you get on the mobile site with the "normal" site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out I was a bit too impatient. The scores are now restored. This happened about 3 hours after the reversal script.

Lesson learnt: proper things do happen but one should be patient.

Comment: I read somewhere once that serial voting reversals didn't affect the denormalised (read: cached) scores. No idea if that's still true, but it's a possible explanation.